# Narrowing Casting problem spoted by Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I'm trying to create a "Truck" using downcasting from the parent class (Truck extends Car)

```
private Truck truck;

public void createTruck() {
    Car basicCar = new Car();
    this.truck = (Truck) basicCar;
}
```

But for some reason Intellij IDEA spots a problem

> Casting 'basicCar' to 'Truck' will produce 'ClassCastException'for any non-null value

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Show the definitions of `Car`, `Truck`, `Sedan`, `Cabriolet` and their relation

Comment: One never instances sub-classes from the class they extend. That's just illogical... the builder pattern might eventually be the closest to what you're trying to accomplish there. The whole type-casting is just pointless ... instead `return new Cabriolet()`.

Comment: You can't cast a `Car` to a `Truck` or `Sedan` or any child class. That's the same as if you'd try to cast an `Object` to a `String`. It doesn't matter that `Truck` implements `Car`, because you instantiated `defaultObj` as `new Car(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Car` will always be a `Car` instance. Unless `Truck`, `Sedan`, and `Cabriolet` are all interfaces, `Car` cannot be all of them at the same time (and it would be weird to have `Car implements Truck, Sedan, Cabriolet`; that doesn't really make sense).

And why are you casting if you are only returning a `Car` from your method anyway? Effectively you execute `return (Car)(Truck)new Car(…);`

You cannot cast objects of the base class to a child class, because the base class doesn't have all the information required to represent instances of the child class.

Consider the following example:

```
class Car {
  int wheels;
  Car(int wheels) { this.wheels = wheels; }
}
class Truck extends Car {
  int weight;
  Truck(int wheels, int weight) {
    super(wheels);
    this.weight = weight;
  }
}

class Program {
  public static void main() {
    Car car = new Car(4);
    Truck truck = (Truck)car;
    // what's the weight of the truck? impossible to know, because a Car is not a Truck
  }
}
```

The above doesn't work, but the following does:

```java
class Program {
  public static void main() {
    Car car = new Truck(4, 1000);
    Truck truck = (Truck)car;
    System.out.println(truck.weight);
  }
}
```

Comment: So I can't do that, right?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. It simply doesn't work like that. Where would the truck instance get its weight from? It has never been assigned and there's no memory allocated for it

Comment: @Aleksandr only if `parrentClass` was assigned a ChildClass instance. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. My mind is messed up by the evening ))

Comment: Yeah I've seen you edit. I've totally forgotten about it for some reason. Sorry for being a little bit stupid